# Can't see view.py in my browser. Django

Tags: python, django

I just installed Django and I created a simple HTML page in my views.py file.  When I try to create the main page URL for the  HTML page, I can't get it to show up.

This is the code I am using in my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from bookmarks.views import *
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^$', main_page),
)
```

What am I missing?  The browser debugger says there is a syntax error on line 2, but I copied it straight from the book.

EDIT:

This is where my syntax error is now (views.py):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def main_page(request):
    output = '''
        <html>
            <head><title>%s</title></head>
            <body>
                <h1>%s</h1><p>%s</p>
            </body>
        </html>
''' % (
    'Django Bookmarks',
    'Welcome to Django Bookmarks',
    'Where you can store and share bookmarks!'
)
return HttpResponse(output)
```

I also copied this from the book...so i'm perplexed

Comment: Are you sure this is the file that has the syntax error?

Comment: At first it did, but now I fixed that.  I do however have a syntax error on views.py.

Comment: i edited my post if you can still help!

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is off:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def main_page(request):
    output = '''
        <html>
            <head><title>%s</title></head>
            <body>
                <h1>%s</h1><p>%s</p>
            </body>
        </html>
    ''' % (
        'Django Bookmarks',
        'Welcome to Django Bookmarks',
        'Where you can store and share bookmarks!'
    )

    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Python uses indentation to denote blocks, so if your code isn't indented properly, it won't run as you'd like it to.

Comment: Ahh, okay.  Thanks!  Perhaps I should learn a bit more about Python before trying anything with Django